# how to make 24 hours time format from string in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to convert a string that was generated by the user to a `Date` data type. I want the time to be in 24-hour format

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
let timeAsString : String = "22:30"
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"

let timeFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: timeAsString)
```

> result : "Jan 1, 2000 at **10:30 PM**"

but the result is in 12-hour format. How can I get 22:30 as a Date data type?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve? A date itself has no format. What is the expected outcome at the end of some code snippet / func?

Comment: is this your full code

Comment: `but the result is in the 12 hour format` — result is `Date.description` string, which uses your system locale format. If you want to print it out if 24h format you should use proper `DateFormatter` instead of just `print(timeFromString)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Date has no format, so only can change the string converted from the date

**Swift 4**

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
 let newDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: yourDate)
```

for different date format, you can check [nsdateformatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com/)

Comment: I upvoted because the link gave me everything I needed. I was searching around for 2 hrs trying to find the abbreviations. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You code is absolutely correct, there no problem in your code. String `HH` in date format represent 24 hours time display format.

But developer (application) has no control over time format. You can set date format string supporting 24 hours time but if user has (not enabled) turned of 24 hours support from device then it will display time for 12 hours format.

Check your simulator/mac system/iPhone device time format and set it for 24 hours display.

Refer this apple document for 24 hours time support: [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

> The representation of the time may be 13:00. In iOS, however, if the user has switched 24-Hour Time to Off, the time may be 1:00 pm.

Comment: Doesn't that mean "Do it without using DateFormatter"?

Comment: No, you should use `DateFormatter` but it will display date according to user's device set up. Suppose if I've set 24 hours date format in my device then according to this code it will show me 24 hour date. Now suppose you've set 12 hours date format in your device then it will show you date in 12 hours format.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to force dateFormatter to use 24-hour format ignoring user's setting? For example if I receive a string from server which is always in 24hour. UPD: Solved it by setting locale to "en_US".

Answer (score 1):

```
func convertToString(of dateTo: Date) -> String {

  let dateFormatter = CustomDateFormatter()

  //Your New Date format as per requirement change it own
  dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" 
  let newDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: dateTo) //pass Date here
  //  print(newDate) //New formatted Date string

  return newDate
 }
```